# jQuery Datepicker not working on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form with a datepicker element.  I had the input at date, but the designer wants the calendar to be opened when the input field is clicked, not from a dropdown arrow.  So, I am using a jQuery datepicker, which works exactly how I want on desktop.  But, when I switch to a mobile view, nothing loads. I am very new to jQuery.

Here is the head script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" 
     src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The script:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     });
```

And a basic version of my html:

```
<p>Date: <input type = "text" id = "datepicker"></p>
```

Any help on why it will not load the page on mobile is very appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to use jquery mobile?

Comment: Is there anything else you can provide to help us troubleshoot this? Using the little bit you've shared, I put together a jsFiddle to try and recreate the problem but it works as expected, even on my mobile device. When you say "switch to a mobile view" are you resizing the browser, emulating a mobile device, anything like that?

Comment: @Dekel That worked, but now the styling on my desktop site is completely wrong.  I tried "data-role: none;" but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JeramiahHarland I am using the inspect on Google Chrome to toggle to a mobile view.  I have it up now, but the styling is all messed up on the desktop page now.  data-role: none doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe not what youneed... but why not use input type="date" and let the native mobile datepickers do the job for you? examples: https://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/4-date.html

Comment: @VA79 That's exactly what I had and it worked great - not what the designer wants, however :(   She would like the calendar to open when the input box is clicked, not by the arrows.